How to dynamically modify hyperparameters during training in Stable Baselines 3?
I'm working with Stable Baselines 3 and I'm trying to implement a training process where I dynamically change hyperparameters at different stages of training. Specifically, I'm using PPO and want to change the gamma parameter.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

# Initial training
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", "CartPole-v1", gamma=0.99)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

print(f"Initial gamma: {model.gamma}")
print(f"Initial rollout buffer gamma: {model.rollout_buffer.gamma}")

# Attempt to change gamma
model.gamma = 0.95
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

print(f"After change - model gamma: {model.gamma}")
print(f"After change - rollout buffer gamma: {model.rollout_buffer.gamma}")

Output:
Initial gamma: 0.99
Initial rollout buffer gamma: 0.99
After change - model gamma: 0.95
After change - rollout buffer gamma: 0.99

As we can see, changing model.gamma doesn't update all the necessary internal states. The model.rollout_buffer.gamma remains unchanged, which can lead to inconsistent behavior.
I've considered saving and reloading the model with new parameters:
model.save("temp_model")
model = PPO.load("temp_model", gamma=0.95)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

print(f"After reload - model gamma: {model.gamma}")
print(f"After reload - rollout buffer gamma: {model.rollout_buffer.gamma}")

Output:
After reload - model gamma: 0.95
After reload - rollout buffer gamma: 0.95

This approach works but seems inefficient, especially if I want to change parameters frequently during training.
Is there a proper way to dynamically update hyperparameters like gamma during training in Stable Baselines 3? Ideally, I'd like a solution that ensures all relevant internal states are updated consistently without having to save and reload the model.
Any insights or best practices for this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
